# Wordpress ACF: Complex search takes too long

Tags: php, wordpress, search, filter, advanced-custom-fields

In the wordpress website I am building I have a custom post (`cp_course`) which has these subfields: `course_code`, `course_duration`, `period_a_start`, `period_a_end`, `period_b_start`, `period_b_end`, `period_c_start`, `period_c_end`, `period_d_start` and  `period_d_end`.

The search form has these fields: `code`, `duration`, `datefrom`, `dateto`. User can search by using any of these. I have only implemented the case that the user uses all search fields:

```
if(!empty($code) && !empty($duration) && !empty($datefrom) && !empty($dateto))
{

    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'cp_course', 'numberposts' =>-1,'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 's' => $searchterm,
        'meta_query' => 
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'   => 'course_code',
                    'value' => $code,
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'course_duration',
                    'value' => $duration,
                ), 
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_a_start',
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($datefrom)),

                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_a_end',
                            'compare' => '<=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($dateto)),

                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_b_start',
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($datefrom)),

                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_b_end',
                            'compare' => '<=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($dateto)),

                        ),
                    ),//IF I REMOVE the follow lines (period_c_* and period_d_*) then it works
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_c_start',
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($datefrom)),

                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_c_end',
                            'compare' => '<=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($dateto)),

                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_d_start',
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($datefrom)),

                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'period_d_end',
                            'compare' => '<=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($dateto)),

                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )

    );

    $course = get_posts($args);

}

<div class="page_title">
                    <h3>Courses</h3>
                </div>

                <?php foreach ($course as $post):setup_postdata($post);?>
                <a href="#"><?php the_title();?></a>

                <?php endforeach;wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

But it doesn't seem working. It's stuck in a loop, already 10 minutes and still searching. What is going wrong?

Is there a simpler logic to implement the different cases than multiple `ifs`? I am going to use something like this but it looks really long and complicated... :

```
if(!empty($code) && !empty($duration) && !empty($datefrom) && !empty($dateto))
{....}
else if(empty($code) && !empty($duration) && !empty($datefrom) && !empty($dateto))
{....}
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I had the same challenge with ACF once.

Running all these ifs would take a lot of time and is not very efficient, I say you try the following method:

***Try building these meta query arrays yourself before running get_posts and initiating `$args` and assign it accordingly, for instance:***

```
    if($code || $duration || $datefrom || $dateto){
        $meta_query = array( array( 'relation' => 'AND' ) );

        if ( $code ) {
            array_push( $meta_query, array(
                array(
                    'key'   => 'course_code',
                    'value' => $code,
                )
            ) );
        }

        if($duration){
            array_push( $meta_query, array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'course_duration',
                    'value' => $duration,
                )
            ) );
        }
//And so on
    }
```

This will definitely be more challenging for nested relations (such as period_a_start), but it's pretty straightforward and the easiest/most efficient way to do it.

Best of luck!